# Sqlite plugin for Eclipse: debug sqlite database on Android device live

Tags: android, database, sqlite, debugging, live

I want to debug database on android device. My application is very heavy and I do too much insertion queries and other stuff so running on emulator is hell slow so I am debugging it on Android phone.

But I could not debug database, like in Iphone you can see even insertion made into database. I want to see the current situation of database without rooting my phone and pulling it from my phone and then opening it into some 3rd party software.

Is there any way to debug Android database on mobile phones without rooting and pulling database out?

There is tool sqlite3 but the problem is that when you connect to shell it shows you ugly data and furthermore if database is not created running any query actually creates database in database folder so you would never knew that your database was not created by your logic.

I hope you understand what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is information on how to connect eclipse to a sqlite database [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Connecting_to_SQLite). Another alternative is using [this](http://code.google.com/p/sqlite-manager/issues/list.) Firefox add-on to manage your sqlite database.

Comment: I applied all steps, but at last a username password combination is required for connection. How can we handle this? My application does not have any username / password to modify SQLite tables

Answer (score 10):

I had the very same problem and after a search I found this one [SQLiteManager plugin for Eclipse](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/04/18/sqlitemanager-plugin-for-eclipse/) which is a plugin for eclipse allowing you to see and browse your data strait from SQLite DB

To use this it's easy, start you emulator, browse the emulator files in the DDMS view then
go to data > data > com.your.package > databases > your_database_name.db (note the db extension is mandatory) 
and a new tab will appear with your data!
It won't work on a real device (maybe on a rooted one?)

Hope it will work for you :)

Comment: Note that viewing the contents of `/data/data` requires root permissions. You could have your app copy the `.db` file to a shared location, but beware that this won't work out of the box for production devices.

Answer (score 2):

I'm still looking into it myself but there is [MOTODEV Studio for Android](https://developer.motorola.com/docstools/motodevstudio/download/), requires free registration.

Comment: but what it does?? I am still reading and didn't know the purpose of this :) plz share your experience

Comment: I've only installed so far but I'll get back to you once I get a chance to play. It should be a GUI which runs on your computer and allows you to investigate SQLite databases living on an attached Android device.

Comment: Hey I have discovered many things. You can see all your database and even can debug. wow and the code snippets works really great. they will reduce time you waste on googling... :) I am loving this. Please tell me about your experience.

Comment: Unfortunately, Google killed MOTODEV Studio (shame!). ADT doesn't come close to the things MDS had.

Comment: Check [this](http://www.pedronveloso.com/2013/08/useful-android-apps-for-developers.html) article, particularly the section on **SQL Editors**.

Answer (score 0):

See the next simple, single JAR file.
[on google code](https://code.google.com/p/android-sqlite-browser-for-eclipse/wiki/HowTo)